How to refer to women in an age range using a compound adjective?
If I want to refer to women in an age range using a compound adjective, are the following formulas correct?

Women from the age of A to B => A-to-B women.
Women over the age of A => over-A women or over-A-year-old women.


"Women over 40" seems more common than "over-40 women", but any of those is OK depending on the context (you shouldn't use a very long noun phrase in some situations). And is there a reason you're asking about women or think it might be different for men?

I think "people over/under  X" is about the only time you can drop the "years old" or "age" bit from the phrase. "40-to-50-year-old women" is idiomatic, though.

10- to 11-Year-Old Children https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27175903/ That is a hyphen with a space, like this: 30- to 40-year old women.

So does their brain look more like an 80-year-old brain of individuals that they match in chronologic age to, or does it look more like a 50- to 60-year-old brain who these people match in cognitive performance to? https://www.apa.org/news/podcasts/speaking-of-psychology/super-ager

The website below provides rules for hyphens.

General Principle 5


When two or more compound modifiers have a common
base, this base is sometimes omitted in all except the last modifier,
but the hyphens are retained.


Long- and short-term memory
2-, 3-, and 10-min trials

So, that gives us:
40- to 60-year-old women
There is a space left after the first hypen in these kinds of cases.
hyphens
https://apastyle.apa.org/learn/faqs/when-use-hyphen

Normally you'd use between:

... women between the ages of 40 and 44.

In some legal documents, where the goal is not to rely on assumptions but to define, it might appear as

... women between the ages of 40 and 44 inclusive

because some lawyer will argue that  without the inclusive modifier the ages involved are 42 and 43.
A compound adjective would not be idiomatic:

*aged-40-to-44 women

but you could say

women aged 40 to 44.


"A compound adjective would not be idiomatic" => it seems that your answer contradicts all three comments above, and it makes it hard for me to settle on this.

Using the age-range as an attributive adjective when the age-range is fronted with aged ( "aged-40-to-44 women") doesn't work, although when it has "year-old" at its tail, it's used often enough: "8-to-10 year-old boys are housed in the cabins by the lake."

Can I write 8-10-year-olds or people aged 8-10 (without "to")? I've just seen these versions and wonder if they are okay.

It is usual to say "children aged 8 to 10" not "people".  8-10-year-olds looks very clumsy, IMO.  I'd use an alternative.
